# New and superior offer right after signing contract

Tags: salary, new-job, resignation, ethics

I have been working for a company for less than a month, and I just receive another offer which I consider really similar, but with a better salary. The issue is that while the workplace of the new offer **seems** great, I have actually spent days in the one with a low salary, which is **actually** a nice environment. Otherwise I would flat out switch.

Ideally, I would like to stay at the current position , and use my offer as leverage to get a better salary. Is it possible ? What is a decent way to approach this situation?

Some context:

- Both positions were currently intended for people with more experience than me
- The current salary is under the median for my profile and level of experience, and 15% less than the one in the offer.
- The company A interviewed me and stayed silent for more than a month.. Then asked me to start the week after the offer. During this time, I had interviews, and the offer from company B dropped after I started working for company A.
- I had to lower my salary expectations when interviewing with company A (which I found odd I cost less than their original target candidates). During the negociation there was a line similar to "We can re-discuss about it for 2014"...
- I found out that my position was vacant for several months, and I match a set of skills which is very rare in the region
- Both companies are small (~ 50)
- The probation period is 3 months with a notice period for the end of the current month (a week min)
- I am not in the US

Comment: If Employer A was slow to get around to you, there's no point in rushing into their arms.  Finish your probationary with company B and then confirm with Company A that they're still interested.  If you like where you are, you should probably savor the environment and live frugally for a few months.

Comment: If it's significantly better, then take it.  If it's marginally better, and you are otherwise happy, then stay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> use my offer as leverage to get a better salary. Is it possible ?

Anything is possible, but it seems unlikely that your current company will give you more money after less than a month of work because of a threat to leave.

More likely will that be they'll just tell you to go now.

When I interview people, I tend to avoid job-hoppers. There's always another offer out there, for a bit more. I like to hire for the long term. If I think the candidate is jumping around repeatedly trying to get a few dollars more, I wont hire them, as I suspect they'll leave as soon as they find the next job paying a little more.

In your case, your timing was off. If you show your current employer that you are a job-hopper, they might give you more money. But more likely is that they'll just say goodbye.

> What is a decent way to approach this situation?

Of all the points you raised, the only one that matters is your probation period. At that point, if you are as rare and valuable as you believe, you can ask for more.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. The move I describe  is a red flag, and means "short term guy". But isn't it a risk for an employer to push for a salary which is below average? Isn't also a short term move from his side?

Answer (score -3):

It is better to stay at the company that you are with right now, once you threaten them with the possibility of resignation they will offer a much higher salary rate for the new employee who they acquired from your position.

During probationary period of your employment expect a low salary rate pay but once they see you that you are performing your job differently from the past employee, who was in your position before, there will be a possibility to increase by double or triple from what you are expecting.

But, do not expect the same way too because there are some companies who don't raise your salary and fail in return after your probationary period. A good decision-making is dependant upon the situation.

Comment: I've tried to re-word this answer, but it wasn't the best written thing I've come across. Can you please make sure I've not accidently removed your context? Can you also please verify why you feel the OP will get a raise after the probationary period? I've known plenty of places that won't do that just because you passed the period. They wait for a year and expect results before even looking at a raise. I also know plenty of other places that will pay you the full wage during a probationary period and won't give you a reduced salary during it